# Show that $E[u(X_1)\mid\sum^n_{i=1}X_i=z]=\Phi \left( \frac{\sqrt n(c-z/n)}{\sqrt{n-1}} \right)$

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, inference, umvue

> Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from the $N(\mu,1)$ distribution. First show that $$E \left[ u(X_1)\, \Big|\, \sum^n_{i=1}X_i=z \right] = \Phi \left( \frac{\sqrt n(c-z/n)}{\sqrt{n-1}} \right)\,,$$ where $u(x)=1$ if $x\leq c$ and $0$ otherwise, and $\Phi(x)=P(Z\leq x)$ where $Z$ is $N(0,1)$ distributed. Then secondly determine the MVUE for $\Phi(c-\mu)$ and compare with the MLE of $\Phi(c-\mu)$ for large $n$.

Please could someone point me in the right direction on this question? I'm not sure where to start on the first part. There is a hint in the question that integration by substitution might help, but I can't even see where integration comes into it. Are there any similar questions out there that you could point me to?

For the second part, I know that a MVUE must attain the Cramer Rao lower bound, but because it's a follow on question from the first part I'm pretty stuck on this as well.

Please could you help get me going or explain to me the process that I need to follow. I'm not looking for someone to tell me the answer - just give me a push to help me get going!

(It may not be relevant, but this question is just a bit from a much bigger question. I've already successfully shown that the MLE of $\mu$ is just the sample mean).

Comment: Please see the answers at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=expectation+truncated+normal.

Comment: The lectures haven't covered truncated normals. Are you sure this is relevant?

Comment: Yes--although certainly one can ignore the connection and still solve the problem.  Regardless, if you look at some of the related answers you will see how this comes down to a straightforward integration, which is what the hint in the question is getting at.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413264/umvue-for-probability-of-cutoff/.

Comment: @whuber But $u(x)=1$ if $x\le c$ and 0 otherwise so $E(u(X_1)|...)=P(X_1<c|...)$ and so doesn't involve the truncated normal.  The rest just follows from joint normality of $X_1$ and $\sum X_i$ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions

Comment: @Jarle This probability is the normalizing constant for a truncated Normal.  The purpose of referencing the answers about truncated Normal expectations was to show what the hint in the question might have been referring to.